# sending objects through TCP socket from java server to android client

Tags: java, android, sockets, serialization, tcp

I was going to use an objectOutputStream but heard this is unreliable because different java versions might deserialize objects differently.  Something about 'horrible cross-architecture practice..'

So how else can I send objects and arrays between these devices, where the receiving end can piece back together the proper object or array data?

Comment: short answer - define and implement a data interchange protocol between your server and client (xml, json, etc)

Comment: How does this approach compare to any other methods? Is that the best way?  If so, why is that the case?  Thanks.  PS that sounds pretty involved for someone who's never done it before :X

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just read what you are doing. You might not need a web server. A lot of people recommend one because of the massive support web servers have. You certainly use TCP or UDP to talk between a server and a client. You'll need to have some protocol if you want data interchange, and most people here would be familiar with XML or JSON

If you need inspiration, try looking at a few protocols like FTP, or even Bittorrent

Web Server case:

I wrote a Java web server for a college homework assignment. A web server actually be quite simple if you have a good grasp on TCP/IP. The code scattered everywhere online to do it though gets a little hard to decipher what exactly is going on, but once you do, it's not bad

You definitely should check out the RFC for HTTP, even though those tend to be worded in legalese. Beyond that, on the server, you basically read strings in line-by-line and you should be able to figure out what to do on the server (example GET /somefile.html HTTP/1.0). Just do System.out.println on those lines and go from there. The same goes for client code. You also can use telnet to see what a web server does

To test, I would actually recommend trying just a regular web browser like Firefox, Chrome, IE, Safari, and even curl scripts. This is an easy test to see if your server is running correctly

As far as data interchange goes, XML or JSON would be recommended, mostly that if you learn how to handle it, you get 100 experience points for your resume. However, to get things started, you can start out just by sending and receiving text like "Wazzzaaap". Web browsers can also grab XML and JSON data.

Comment: I do kind of want to avoid webservers and HTTP unless and until it becomes obvious that my needs can't be suited with the current implementation.  So how can JSON or XML be used to for instance, transfer an arraylist or more complicated object?

Answer (score -1):

By 'java server', what kind of protocols are you using?

One option is RPC, which is defined in java.rmi

If you are using http, the simplest choice is to implement a small servlet in tomcat/jetty and use restful services

The data format can be xml, json, bin, etc

Comment: It's literally just a server written in java.  All it does so far is receive a socket with:  ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(9999); then for each connection Socket newsock = sock.accept(); and it creates a thread to read and respond to the incoming lines.  Protocols?
Would TCP/IP be the answer?  I'm not using anything restful.

Comment: TCP specificially would be the answer

Comment: Ah, I had that in title and tag I thought.  So what would be my options in that case?

Comment: the server socket will not let you send data from server to client, it just waits for communication
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html

Comment: Honestly, the answer is "it depends". You actually might not need a full-blown web server. TCP is good for cases where you need reliable data, and UDP would be used if you don't care if the data makes it to the destination. Web servers have the advantage that they have a lot of support behind them and are tried-and-tested. However, for really high-performance interchange between server and client, it might not be the ideal case

Comment: Joe, What kind of things do you mean when  you say "lots of support behind them"?  I truly don't think what I'm doing would require or be made easier by making a webserver or using http.